# How to analyse the memory consumed embedded H2 database which is running Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, h2, tomcat9

H2 jar is placed in WEB-INF\lib folder of Tomcat. Embedded H2 DB is running inside Tomcat 9.0.14.I just wanted to analyse the memory usage by H2 DB.

I am able to get the total heap memory usage by tomcat. But not able to find the memory usage by H2 DB process.

Answer (score 0):

Should your app is the sole app to access your db, try to check this out.

```
http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html
```

You can also use tomcat manager

```
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Introduction
```